# Script Error Pops Up Every 15 minutes or so

Tags: windows-7

I have an end user that sees the popup in the screenshot attached that says "Script Error" every 15 minutes or so. I don't see anything in the event viewer to indicate the problem.

Anybody have any ideas? Seems like it has something to do with something tied in to Google but I haven't been able to figure it out.

[image: Script Error popup]

User is running Windows 7 Professional 32-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the contents of the error dialog, it appears that a Windows Desktop Gadget from [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig) is the cause of the problem.  If such a gadget exists on the desktop, try removing it from the desktop; if this doesn't work, uninstall the gadget; right-click on the desktop, select **Gadgets**, right-click on the gadget in question, and click **Uninstall**.  This problem may also be caused by [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com).

A part of the URL listed, http://www.gmodules.com, redirects to google.com, so the gadget is probably supplied by Google.

Comment: Thanks for the input dragon. As soon as I can get in touch with the user to connect again I will take a look at this and award you the point if this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is some problem with youtube gadget in the iGoogle user page. Maybe an ivalid video, I'm not sure.